What is my RAM used for?
This program:
import psutil

def get_process_memory_usage():
    process_list = []
    total_process_memory = 0

    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'memory_info']):
        try:
            mem_info = proc.info['memory_info']
            mem_usage_mb = mem_info.rss / (1024 * 1024)  # Convert bytes to MB
            process_list.append((proc.info['pid'], proc.info['name'], mem_usage_mb))
            total_process_memory += mem_usage_mb
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass

    return process_list, total_process_memory

def get_detailed_memory_info():
    detailed_info = {}

    # Try to get memory details from /proc/meminfo
    try:
        with open('/proc/meminfo') as f:
            meminfo = f.readlines()
        meminfo_dict = {line.split(':')[0]: int(line.split(':')[1].strip().split()[0]) for line in meminfo}

        # Add relevant fields to detailed_info
        detailed_info.update({
            "slab": meminfo_dict.get('Slab', 0) / 1024,  # Slab memory in MB
            "kernel_stack": meminfo_dict.get('KernelStack', 0) / 1024,  # Kernel stack memory in MB
            "page_tables": meminfo_dict.get('PageTables', 0) / 1024,  # Page tables memory in MB
            "vmalloc_used": meminfo_dict.get('VmallocUsed', 0) / 1024,  # vmalloc used in MB
            "hardware_reserved": meminfo_dict.get('HardwareCorrupted', 0) / 1024,  # Hardware reserved memory in MB
        })
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error gathering detailed memory info: {e}")

    return detailed_info

def display_memory_info():
    # Gather overall memory statistics
    vm = psutil.virtual_memory()

    total_memory = vm.total / (1024 * 1024)  # Convert bytes to MB
    used_memory = vm.used / (1024 * 1024)
    free_memory = vm.free / (1024 * 1024)
    shared_memory = vm.shared / (1024 * 1024)
    buff_cache_memory = (vm.buffers + vm.cached) / (1024 * 1024)
    available_memory = vm.available / (1024 * 1024)

    # Display overall memory statistics
    print(f"Memory Usage Analysis:")
    print(f"{'='*23}")
    print(f"Total Memory: {total_memory:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Used Memory: {used_memory:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Free Memory: {free_memory:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Shared Memory: {shared_memory:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Buff/Cache: {buff_cache_memory:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Available Memory: {available_memory:.2f} MB")
    print()

    # Get and display process memory usage
    process_list, total_process_memory = get_process_memory_usage()
    expected_memory_usage = used_memory - (shared_memory + buff_cache_memory)
    detailed_memory_info = get_detailed_memory_info()

    print("Process Memory Usage (Top Processes):")
    print(f"{'='*37}")
    for pid, name, mem_usage in sorted(process_list, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)[:10]:  # Display top 10 processes
        print(f"PID: {pid}, Name: {name}, Memory Usage: {mem_usage:.2f} MB")

    print(f"\nTotal Process Memory Usage: {total_process_memory:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Expected Process Memory Usage: {expected_memory_usage:.2f} MB")

    if total_process_memory < expected_memory_usage:
        difference = expected_memory_usage - total_process_memory
        print(f"\nDifference: {difference:.2f} MB")
        print("Detailed Non-Process Memory Usage:")
        print(f"{'='*33}")
        for key, value in detailed_memory_info.items():
            print(f"{key.replace('_', ' ').title()}: {value:.2f} MB")

        detailed_memory_total = sum(detailed_memory_info.values())
        print(f"\nTotal Non-Process Memory Usage: {detailed_memory_total:.2f} MB")

        remaining_difference = difference - detailed_memory_total
        print(f"\nUnaccounted Memory Usage: {remaining_difference:.2f} MB")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_memory_info()

gives this output:
Memory Usage Analysis:
=======================
Total Memory: 31913.30 MB
Used Memory: 21006.95 MB
Free Memory: 9526.90 MB
Shared Memory: 435.57 MB
Buff/Cache: 1379.44 MB
Available Memory: 9866.04 MB

Process Memory Usage (Top Processes):
=====================================
PID: 561032, Name: firefox, Memory Usage: 991.64 MB
PID: 4692, Name: kwin_x11, Memory Usage: 197.31 MB
PID: 3276884, Name: WebExtensions, Memory Usage: 147.34 MB
PID: 3315683, Name: Isolated Web Co, Memory Usage: 88.94 MB
PID: 3334903, Name: Isolated Servic, Memory Usage: 88.25 MB
PID: 1225402, Name: konsole, Memory Usage: 77.89 MB
PID: 3327683, Name: Isolated Web Co, Memory Usage: 71.01 MB
PID: 4725, Name: plasmashell, Memory Usage: 69.02 MB
PID: 4328, Name: Xorg, Memory Usage: 47.75 MB
PID: 3277076, Name: Isolated Web Co, Memory Usage: 46.05 MB

Total Process Memory Usage: 3465.15 MB
Expected Process Memory Usage: 19191.94 MB

Difference: 15726.79 MB
Detailed Non-Process Memory Usage:
=================================
Slab: 4130.64 MB
Kernel Stack: 43.08 MB
Page Tables: 200.25 MB
Vmalloc Used: 189.30 MB
Hardware Reserved: 0.00 MB

Total Non-Process Memory Usage: 4563.28 MB

Unaccounted Memory Usage: 11163.51 MB

I am clearly missing some important part here: What is taking up the 11 GB? (And can I figure out what the 4 GB slab is used for?)
(Before running I tried forcing everything to be swapped out with swapout, which slowly builds a data structure that is the size of physical RAM before releasing everything. So everything that is left in RAM is memory allocations that cannot be swapped out for some reason).
Edit: I killed processes one at a time. 2 VLC processes each lowered the unaccounted amount by 3.5GB. These 3.5GB is reserved in such a way that it refuses to be swapped out, and it also avoid being measured by my program.
How can I change the script to detect the correct value for these VLC processes (and other processes that do similar trickery)?

Maybe ps_mem could help

@PabloA ps_mem detects 4.4 GB used by processes on my system now. That is less than the above which detects 6710.59 MB used by processes. So it seems to be even worse at detecting use. Which of the two worked better on your system?

RAM is consumed by programs, shared libraries, I/O buffers, caches of many types, and is allocated/freed on a microsecond by microsecond basis. If you ask twice, as quickly as you can, you will get differing results.

I didn't try that program, is from a GitHub project? If so, please add it to the post please

Note that memory use numbers pulled live are estimates at best.  Not only do you get sampling errors with overlapping time intervals causing issues, but programs themselves can share memory and it can be double counted and it is very difficult to get an accurate use number unless you examine each page and check how many things are using it.

tmpfs? what's the output of df | grep tmpfs?

@waltinator I get consistent results if I run the program multiple times: The unaccounted part varies very little.

@PabloA Are you asking if my program is from GitHub? It is not. It is written for this question only.

@user10489 I am OK running a program as root, so it can analyze everything. I just want that the unaccounted part is minimal - not 1/3 of my RAM.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov tmpfs is counted in my program in "Buff/Cache". If you add 1 GB to a tmpfs, you will see that value increase 1 GB. So tmpfs is part of the memory that is accounted for.

I can only think of your AMD/Intel GPU driver leaking RAM and AFAIK both can use/allocate system RAM if needed. I'm not sure your script handles it. glxinfo -B shows something but it's not system RAM, on my system: Dedicated video memory: 12282 MB     Total available memory: 12282 MB     Currently available dedicated video memory: 11077 MB

@ArtemS.Tashkinov That is an interesting idea, and explains why VLC is to blame. My output has only two lines with mem: Video memory: 1536MB does not account for 2x 3GB, but Unified memory: yes might - this could be reserved through unusual ways. So how do I figure out how much unified mem is used?

I don't have a deep knowledge of the kernel, so I cannot answer you question.
